# Is something like "the number of items selected with a certain property" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I am wondering whether the following sentence is correct.

> The algorithm counts the number of items selected with a certain property.

To me, this sounds somewhat incorrect. It's hard to pinpoint why, but I think it has to do with the "with a certain property" being a further description of "items". This makes me think that the "selected" shouldn't come in between.

To me, either of the following options sounds correct:

1. The algorithm counts the number of selected items with a certain
   property.
2. The algorithm counts the number of items with a certain
   property selected.

And out of these two options, my preference goes to the first.

However, regardless of preference, I am wondering whether the sentence I proposed in the beginning of this post is correct?

Comment: Sounds fine, but you could use "that have a certain property" if you'd prefer.

Comment: Do you need the word "selected" at all?

Comment: The algorithm counts the number of items with a certain property **that have been** selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that someone/something has selected *n* items, and that 0–*n* of those items will have a particular property, and that those items that have that particular property will be counted, then:

> *The algorithm counts the number of selected items that have a particular property.*

*The number of* might be redundant:

> *The algorithm counts selected items having a particular property.*